# passing string value to Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-xml

Am just stuck to pass my string variable to my Data Access layer.

here is my main console

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
            String BookingTime="1000345";
            var BookingStart = new SchedSAPEntities.ResourceBookingEntity.ResourceBooking(string Bookingtime);
   }
```

}

SchedSAPEntities.ResourceBookingEntity.ResourceBooking(string Bookingtime);//Am trying to pass the string variable (1000345) to ResourceBooking method.

Here is my Data access Layer

```
 public class ResourceBookingEntity
{
    public class ResourceBooking
    {
        private String _PRJ_ID;

        public ResourceBooking(String APRJ_ID )
        {
            _PRJ_ID = APRJ_ID;

        }
        public String PRJ_ID { get { return _PRJ_ID; } }
        }
}


  public class ResourceBookingList : List<SchedSAPEntities.ResourceBookingEntity.ResourceBooking>
    {
        public ResourceBookingList(SchedwinEntities db)
        {
                var query =
                (from PROJECTS in db.PROJECTS
                 join WOes in db.WOes on PROJECTS.PRJ_ID equals WOes.PRJ_ID
                 join SEVT_EX in db.SEVT_EX on SEVTs.SESID equals SEVT_EX.SESID into SEVT_EX_join
                 from SEVT_EX in SEVT_EX_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where
                   (new string[] { "1", "2" }).Contains((PROJECTS.STAT.TrimEnd()).TrimStart()) &&
                   (WOes.STAT.TrimEnd()).TrimStart() == "6" &&
                   ((SEVTs.RESTYPE == 5 ||
                   SEVTs.RESTYPE == 0) &&
                   **SEVTs.T_START.TrimStart() == BookingStart**//Am trying to pass the value here
                 orderby
                   PROJECTS.PRJ_ID,
                   WOes.WONUM
                 select new
                 {
                     PROJECTS.PRJ_ID,

                 }).Take(10);
            foreach (var r in query)
                Add(new SchedSAPEntities.ResourceBookingEntity.ResourceBooking(
                    r.PRJ_ID, r.USER3, r.USER9, r.WONUM));
                    var ResourceBooking = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what line in your code are you having problems with..? what do the lines of code with the `**  **` mean..? this is entirely too much code for someone on here to go thru line by line and trying to figure out your logic and our your thought process.. also what are you hard coding values for example `String BookingTime="1000345";` I think you need to reformat your question in a mannere where someone can understand your question..

Comment: Thanks DJ, i will reformat my question anyway,what am trying to do is pass the "String BookingTime="1000345";" to my data access layer (one in **) thru entity,is that make sense ?

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting? Just saying that you are "stuck" is not a real helpful description of your problem. My guess is that you are get errors at compile time.

Comment: When i try to add "bookingtime" in Resourcebooking it throws "It doesn't exist in the current Context"

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to pass the type into the method, and remember C# is case sensitive.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
            String BookingTime="1000345";
            var BookingStart = new SchedSAPEntities.ResourceBookingEntity.ResourceBooking(BookingTime);
   }
```

Comment: hi dbugger, thanks for your answer my problem is passing this string value to "public ResourceBooking(String APRJ_ID )", it doesn't accept if add a new variable here like "public ResourceBooking(String APRJ_ID, string BookingTime)"